# Prove A and B are congruent

Tags: alternative-proof, solution-verification

#### Prove A and B are congruent

---

where $i_1i_2\text{...}i_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,\text{...},n$

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### My proof.

---

Swapping two elements in the diagonal of Matrix A is identical to swapping two rows, and then swapping two columns, thus the same to the effect that multiply A with a elementary matrix from left and right meanwhile.

so an arbitrary permutation of diagonal could be composed by several manipulations above. `And` the composition matrix of elementary matrices are invertible. Hence there exists invertible matrix $C=C'$ such that $A=C'\text{BC}$

Correct?
Welcome alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if we let $A=(A_{ij})$ where
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & & & \\
& \lambda_2 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & \lambda_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $B=(B_{ij})$ where
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{\sigma(1)} & & & \\
& \lambda_{\sigma(2)} & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & \lambda_{\sigma(n)} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then $$PAP^T=B$$ where $P=(P_{ij})$ is the [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) for $\sigma$.

To prove this, we see
\begin{align*}
(PA)_{ij} &= P_{i1}A_{1j}+P_{i2}A_{2j}+\cdots+P_{in}A_{nj} \\
   &= A_{\sigma(i)j}
\end{align*}
since $P_{ij}=1$ if $j=\sigma(i)$ and $P_{ij}=0$ otherwise.  Hence 
\begin{align*}
B_{ij} &= (PAP^T)_{ij} \\
   &= (PA)_{i1}(P^T)_{1j}+(PA)_{i2}(P^T)_{2j}+\cdots+(PA)_{in}(P^T)_{nj} \\
   &= (PA)_{i\sigma(j)} \\
   &= A_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}.
\end{align*}
We conclude that $$B_{ii}=A_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i)}=\lambda_{\sigma(i)}$$ for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $$B_{ii}=A_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}=0$$ for $i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $i \neq j$.

We can see that $P$ is invertible for a range of reasons, e.g., its inverse is the permutation matrix for $\sigma^{-1}$, or it's row equivalent to the identity matrix via swapping rows.

Thus $A$ and $B$ are congruent.